# mass out on the street's meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context

Scene: In the house, loud helicopter's sound outside.

> But beside that, it is as quiet as mass out on the street.

What does this as quiet as mass out mean? it is quite because no one is in the house? (Mass (people) are on the street)?

Novel, Pines, Blake Crouch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for a different meaning of "mass", specifically, the first part of this definition:

> a religious ceremony in some Christian Churches based on Jesus' last meal with his disciples, or music written for parts of this ceremony:

(source: [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mass)).

In short, it's as quiet out on the street as it is during a mass in a church.